# How to collect a polynomial with a specific power

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

Suppose I have got this polynomial

u=x^12-3x^8-x^4+3

Now, I am trying to collect this polynomial with x^4 terms.
I need to write it like this: (-1+x^4) (-3 + x^4) (1 + x^4)

To evaluate it, I used

Factor[u]

(-1 + x) (1 + x) (1 + x^2) (-3 + x^4) (1 + x^4)

and

Collect[%, x^4, Simplify]

3 - x^4 - 3 x^8 + x^12

But, finally I am not able to reach what I need. Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5):

Still another option is

```
Factor[u /. x^n_ -> y^(n/4)] /. y -> x^4

(* (-3 + x^4) (-1 + x^4) (1 + x^4) *)
```

Comment: Simpler: `Factor[u /. x -> y^(1/4)] /. y -> x^4`

Comment: Also, if you want your pattern to match a simple `x` too (not just higher powers of $x$), you'll need a [default pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html): `x^n_. -> y^(n/4)` (notice the dot after the underscore).

Comment: @Roman  In this case there is no need "to match a simple `x` too".  I can imagine other computations in which `Default` would be useful, however  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in several ways. How about this:
First,

```
u = x^12 - 3 x^8 - x^4 + 3;
    
    u1 = Factor[u]
    
    (*   (-1 + x) (1 + x) (1 + x^2) (-3 + x^4) (1 + x^4)  *)
```

Then

```
Simplify[Drop[u1, -2]]*Drop[u1, 3]

(*  (-3 + x^4) (-1 + x^4) (1 + x^4)  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

You could do a `SolveAlways` to get the values `a[i]` below, provided you know in advance the number of factors:

```
prod[x_, n_] := Product[x^4 + a[i], {i, n}]
sol = SolveAlways[x^12 - 3 x^8 - x^4 + 3 == prod[x, 3], x];

prod[x, 3] /. sol[[1]]

(* (-3 + x^4) (-1 + x^4) (1 + x^4) *)
```